# Error in Install-Package Microsoft.CodeAnalysis -Version 1.3.2

Tags: roslyn, roslyn-code-analysis

I trying to install Microsoft Roslyn through NuGet packages.

```
PM> Install-Package Microsoft.CodeAnalysis -Version 1.3.2
Attempting to resolve dependency 'Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.Workspaces (= 1.3.2)'.
Attempting to resolve dependency 'Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp (= 1.3.2)'.
Attempting to resolve dependency 'Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Common (= 1.3.2)'.
Attempting to resolve dependency 'System.Collections.Immutable (≥ 1.1.37)'.
Attempting to resolve dependency 'System.Reflection.Metadata (≥ 1.2.0)'.
Install-Package : 'System.Reflection.Metadata' already has a dependency defined for 'System.Collections.Immutable'.
At line:1 char:16
+ Install-Package <<<<  Microsoft.CodeAnalysis -Version 1.3.2
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Install-Package], InvalidOperationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NuGetCmdletUnhandledException,NuGet.PowerShell.Commands.InstallPackageCommand
```

Comment: This sounds like [this issue](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/12780). What version of VS and NuGet are you using?

Comment: @svick I use Visual Studio 2012.

Comment: Then I think you will have to upgrade. The [download page for NuGet](https://dist.nuget.org/index.html) does not list any up-to-date version of NuGet for VS 2012.